# Pandas - Converting dataframe object to numbers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, sparse-matrix, dtype

I have a dataframe which looks like this.

```
x_train.info()

Int64Index: 8330 entries, 16 to 8345
Data columns (total 4 columns):
userId                    8330 non-null object
base_id                   8330 non-null object
rating                    8330 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
```

I am trying to convert this to sparse matrix using the following command

```
train_sparse_matrix = sparse.csc_matrix((x_train['rating'].values, (x_train['userId'].values, x_train['base_id'].values)),)
```

**But I get the following error**

```
<ipython-input-112-520f5e1aee89> in <module>
      4 
      5 train_sparse_matrix = sparse.csc_matrix((x_train['result.courseViewCount'].values, (x_train['userId'].values, 

----> 6                                                             **x_train['result.base_id'].values)),)**

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

So I tried converting this dataframe using `.astype('int32)` and `to_numeric()` function but the `x_train.info()` still keeps showing as object.

Can you please help!

Data would be something like this:

```
userId  base_id rating  
5392.0  ABC001  6.0 
5392.0  ETZ222  2.0 
5392.0  XYZ095  1.0 

Is it because the base_id contains alphabets?
```

Comment: Try using `train_sparse_matrix = sparse.csc_matrix((np.array(x_train['rating'].values), np.array(x_train['userId'].values, x_train['base_id'].values)),)`, it may help!

Comment: It did not work, gives me the same error (numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try converting it to numpy.int64?

```
.astype(numpy.int64)
```

If you give an extract of the real data, it will be helpful to answer

Comment: User id data would be  something like this  - 5340.0, 5555.0, 6540.0 etc, rating would be like 6.0, 1.0, 3.0 etc and base_id would be ETB223, ABC001, XYZ533. Would this help? I tried .astype(numpy.int64), but it did not work.  I am starting to feel that the base_id contains alphabets, would that be the reason?

Comment: Which column are you trying to convert to float? The user id and rating column are already in float data type. The base_id contains alpha numeric characters. You can't convert them to float or int.

Comment: The sparse matrix accepts only int so I was trying to covert to int but it is not working.

Comment: You cant convert "ABC" to an int or float value. What are your expected results for the example that you have shared?